# switch character in line linux

Tags: linux, sed

This is file that I got

```
 1  CAGGAAAGACAATTCCAAAATCAGTTAGAGTCCTGTTGGCGCGTGTAATACATCTCCACTTTGAAAATGAAGACAGGGGGTTACGAGTGTTATTAATGAG
 2  TGGGAATGTAAATTAGTCCAGCCACTCTGGAGAACCGTATGGAGGTTCCTCCAAAAATTACAAATAGAACTACCATATGATCCAGCAATCCCATGCTATG
 3  AGATTTCCCTGAGAAAGTCATATTTAAGCTGCCATTTGAAGACCAAGGAATCATGACTAGAGACAAGAAGAGAGAACATAGAGTGATTATGGAGAATCTT
 4  AGTATCAGTCCAGTCCTCAGTGACGGGACCCTAACTGACCTGCCCTTCTTTGGCTTAGATTGCTTAAATGGTTCTGGATGTGATGATGGTGCACCTTGCC
 5  TATATTAGAGTAGAGTCTAAAGATTAGAATGATCCACAGGTTAATATGGGCCATTATAAAGAGATTAGTGATATTAACAATNTAGTATCAACATGGAGAT
 6  TCTATTATTTCATTGGGGTTGCAAAATTGTGATTTTCTAATCATTTCACTTTTCCTATATTTATTGCCTGGAACTTTGTAAAGAAGAAATTGATCTTATT
 7  TACCCTCAGGCTTATTAGGGTTGGAAACTCCACCCTGGGAAATTTGTGGTCAGACAGGTTTTCTGCTCTGGAACACTTTTTTCTGTTGTTTAAGATTTTT
 8  GCAAGAGAATCACTTGAACCCAGGAGGCAGAGGTTGCAGTGAGCCGGGATCGCGCCACTGCACTTCAGCCTGGGTGACAGTGTGAGACTCCATCTCAAAA
 9  TCACTGGTATTAAATCCCCAAATCAGAAATTTTGGACTGATTAAAAAAATGCACCAATCAAACAACAGAATTTCACACCAGATTTTGATAGTATACTTAT
10  GTAAACTACTTGTGAATATTTTTAATTAATGGCAATGTGGTTGCTTGCATACATTTAATAACAACATGTTTTATTTTATAANGGGCCATAACTGGAGGAA
11  TTCTTTTGAACTACTGAATCTCTGAGAACACTTAACAGGGTGAAGTTCAGTATTTACTTATTATTGTGAATCTGATAGCTGAAGTGATTTTTGTACAGCA
12  TCCCAAAGTGCTGGGATGACAGGCGTGAGCCACCGCGCCCGGCCCAAAGGAATTACTTTTAACTAAGAAACCTCCCACCCACCTCCTCCAGTTGCTATAT
13  CCGATCTTCAGGTTCTAAATTATGAAGTGGTTGATGGTCCTCAATAAGTGAACCATGAAATGCTTTCTTTACCTGGTGAAAATACATGGTGGTATAATAA
```

Each character in file represent nucleotide sequence, and I'm trying to switch it in complement one, and change it in reversed direction.

which

```
G -> C , C->G , A->U, T -> A
```

sample input & output will be

```
input
CAAATGGG

output
CCCAUUUG
```

I tried

```
 sed -i 's/C/G/g' file | sed -i 's/G/C/g' file | sed -i 's/A/U/g' file | sed -i 's/T/A/g' file
```

but dind't worㅏ

Comment: Are you sure A should be translated to U and not to T?

Comment: @mathguy yes it was given in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you chain your `sed` commands as shown it will keep remapping the letter.

You can actually do the letter mapping, without the reverse, very simply with `tr` which is designed to do character by character translation: `tr "GCAT" "CGUA" file`. `tr` translates each character in the first string, in turn, to the corresponding character in the second string. Then to get the reversed string, you can use `rev`. So in all:

```
cat file | tr "GCAT" "CGUA" | rev
```

Or better (as @edmorton suggests), when directly from the file:

```
tr "GCAT" "CGUA" < file | rev
```

You can avoid the redirection, as @mathguy suggests, but changing the order (since `rev` accepts a file argument, whereas `tr` does not):

```
rev file | tr "CATG" "GUAC"
```

Example:

```
$ echo "CAAATGGG" | tr "CATG" "GUAC" | rev
CCCAUUUG
```

Comment: If you reverse first and then translate, you don't need input redirection; `rev` accepts input files as arguments. (Oddly, `tr` does not.)

Comment: Thanks @mathguy, good thought. I agree, it is odd that `tr` does not accept a file argument. It's a bit off-standard of most other basic Linux/Unix commands.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i 'y/GCAT/CGUA/;G;:a;s/(.)(\n.*)/\2\1/;ta;s/.//' file
```

Translate the characters G,C,S and T to C,G,U and A.

Reverse the line by introducing a newline as a delimiter and adding the last character of the original line to the front of the new reversed line to be. When there are no further characters to add, remove the newline, voila!

Alternative:

```
sed -i 'y/GCAT/CGUA/;s/.*/echo "&"|rev/e' file
```